# Pandas: Extract string after maximum nth delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this:

```
        A_1         A_2         B_1         B_2         C_1         C_2
DP0001  11:01:01    11:01:01    15:35       51:02:01    07:02:04    15:02:01:01
DP0002  02:01:01:02 26:01:01    35:01:01:01 40:01:02    04:82       08:01:01
DP0003  11:01:01    11:01:01:01 15:02:01    56:04       01:02:01    08:01:01
DP0004  11:01:01    34:01:01    15:02:01    15:12       03:03:01:03 08:01:01
```

I want to extract the string before at most 3 `:`. The desire output:

```
        A_1         A_2         B_1         B_2         C_1         C_2
DP0001  11:01:01    11:01:01    15:35       51:02:01    07:02:04    15:02:01
DP0002  02:01:01    26:01:01    35:01:01    40:01:02    04:82       08:01:01
DP0003  11:01:01    11:01:01    15:02:01    56:04       01:02:01    08:01:01
DP0004  11:01:01    34:01:01    15:02:01    15:12       03:03:01    08:01:01
```

I tried multiple ways but none is successful so far:

1. Using regex:

```
    df.stack().str.extract('^([\w]+:[\w]+:[\w]+)').unstack()[0]
```

However, it cannot capture string with only 1 `:` and return NaN for such case.

2. Using split then join strategy

```
    def six_digits(df_columns):
        return df_columns.str.split(':', expand=True).iloc[:, :3].apply(':'.join, axis=1)
    
    df.apply(lambda x: six_digits(x))
```

Then it encounters `None` at cell with only `:` and throws an error.

Could you please advise me how to deal with this case? Thank you

Comment: ```^([\w]+:){1,3}``` in regex could solve the problem

Comment: I think it's not working, it resulted only the digits before the first `:`

Comment: ```([\w]+:[\w]+:?[\w]+)``` how about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `DataFrame.replace`

```
df.replace(r'^(\w+:\w+:\w+)(:.+)?', r'\1', regex=True)
```

---

```
             A_1       A_2       B_1       B_2       C_1       C_2
DP0001  11:01:01  11:01:01     15:35  51:02:01  07:02:04  15:02:01
DP0002  02:01:01  26:01:01  35:01:01  40:01:02     04:82  08:01:01
DP0003  11:01:01  11:01:01  15:02:01     56:04  01:02:01  08:01:01
DP0004  11:01:01  34:01:01  15:02:01     15:12  03:03:01  08:01:01
```

**Regex details:**

- `^` : Assert position at the start of line
- `(\w+:\w+:\w+)` : First capturing group

  - `\w+` : Matches any word character one or more times
  - `:`  : Matches the character `:` literally
- `(:.+)` : Second capturing group

  - `:` : Matches the character `:` literally
  - `.+` : Matches any character one or more times
- `?` : Matches the previous token between zero and one time

See the online [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/7acPQY/1)

Comment: Thanks, it works wonderfully. 

In case I want to extend the question a bit, such as capturing `11:01:01` from `11:01:01G`, I changed the regex to '^(\w+:\w+:\d+)(:.+)?', it shows on the regex101 to be correctly captured, but when I use  `df.replace(r'^(\w+:\w+:\d+)(:.+)?', r'\1', regex=True)`, it still returns `11:01:01G` . How can I fix this?

Comment: @ThanhNguyen Check with `^(\w+:\w+:\d+)(.+)?`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Simple explanation would be: using replace function and mentioning regex to match 2 digits colon 2 digits colon 2 digits and leaving everything else as its not needed as per OP's samples.

```
df.astype(str).replace(r'^((?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2})(.*)', r'\1', regex=True)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
             A_1       A_2       B_1       B_2       C_1       C_2
DP0001  11:01:01  11:01:01     15:35  51:02:01  07:02:04  15:02:01
DP0002  02:01:01  26:01:01  35:01:01  40:01:02     04:82  08:01:01
DP0003  11:01:01  11:01:01  15:02:01     56:04  01:02:01  08:01:01
DP0004  11:01:01  34:01:01  15:02:01     15:12  03:03:01  08:01:01
```